# Smart tv application launch by channel

Tags: android, smart-tv

I would like to know if it's possible to launch an application for smart tv by selecting a specific channel?

(i.e. I launch my application if I select the channel 101).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you are in Europe, then no. Applications generally cannot be launched over traditional DTT content. There are excpetions, for example if you are the broadcaster you could request special permission to do it, and the CE would consider on a case by case basis. These are the so called ticker apps. The reason this is not possible is that a broadcaster wouldn't want part of the screen covered with an app from a third party. So ticker apps are not allowed generally except on a case by case basis if they are from the same manufacturer. 
In the US the rules are more relaxed and you can have ticker apps over DTT content.